# Firebase Cloud Messaging Ignoring APNS key

Tags: firebase, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send a notification to my device using the apns key as described here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages#ApnsConfig.

The push notification does arrive, but the title is not overridden. When I omit the `notification` key, the notification is only send (in the background) when I add the `content_available: true` option.

This is what my body looks like:

```
{
    "to" : <TOKEN>,
    "apns" : {
        "payload" : {
            "aps" : {
                "alert" : "Does not work",
                "badge" : 1,
                "sound" : "bingbong.aiff"
            }
        }
    } 
    "notification" : { 
        "body" : "Works" 
    }
}
```

Whatever combination I try, it looks like Firebase is ignoring the apns key. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How did it solve for you ? (assuming it worked for you eventually)

Comment: I only used the notification key in the end.

Comment: did anyone find a solution to this?

Comment: Anyone found a working solution after 4 years? :D

Answer (score 1):

You are using legacy API for sending push notifications (not V1). 
Legacy API doesn't support extra keys like Android or APNs.

So you have two options here:

1. Keep using legacy API, here's protocol description for it: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref
   Keep in mind you'll not be able to use specific Android or APNs keys.
2. Move to API v1. It lets you use all keys but it requires setting up server for OAuth2. 
   https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages#ApnsConfig